# Monitoring a member of an associative array

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have an associative array called `array`, on which I'm trying to do the following:

```
initial
begin
 $monitor ("array[10]=%h", array[32'h20]);
end
```

I need to know whenever there is a change on this member. But I get the following error:

`Associative array may not be used in non-procedural context.`

Can someone tell me how and if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works in Modelsim/Questa going to versions back 10 years. You might try

```
always @(array[32'h20]) $displayh(array['h20]);
```